# Why a default constructed object in Python contains the data of a previously used other object?

Tags: python, dictionary, object, constructor

I have a class `Foo` that takes by default an empty dictionary `{}` in its `__init__()` function.

I instantiate a first object `a` and fill its dictionary.

Then, I instantiate a second object `b`, and I was expecting this object to be empty... but no, it contains the data of the previously used object `a`, why?

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, data={}):
        self.data = data

a = Foo()
a.data[0] = 'one'
a.data[1] = 'two'
a.data[2] = 'three'
print(a.data) # {0: 'one', 1: 'two', 2: 'three'}

b = Foo()
print(b.data) # {0: 'one', 1: 'two', 2: 'three'} instead of {}, why?
```

Comment: Because every time that `Foo()` is called without passing a separate `data`, **the same `dict` object** is used as the default value. Please read the linked duplicate (an extremely common one) for details.